# Liquid Round Display number as whole if number is 0 after decimal and display same price if there is a number after 0 tried round:1 but didn't work

Tags: html, rounding, liquid, crm, dataverse

i want to show a price as a whole number if the number after decimal is 0
but if the price has any specific number after the decimal then it should display the same price

tried  round:1 but didn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Provide two examples with expected output and curent output

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove ".00" after the price

```
{{ product.price | money | remove: '.00' }}
```

If you will haven't ".00" it will just skip it